# Finding pairings using small amount number of bits

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

There are 20 unknown unique pairs of 16-bit sequences $(a_i, b_i)$:
$$a_i = (a_{i,0}, a_{i,1}, ..., a_{i,15}), a_{i,k} \in \{0,1\}$$
$$b_i = (b_{i,0}, b_{i,1}, ..., b_{i,15}), b_{i,k} \in \{0,1\}$$
$i=1,2,3,..., 20$

I know two sets:
$$A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{20}\}$$
$$B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_{20}\}$$

How, using only questions

> Is there a pair, such that...

where all given parameters are in total at last 20 bits long, find all pairings?

I was thinking about [describing set $A$ and $B$ using 5 4-bit numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271483/reducing-ammount-of-bits-required-to-identify-an-object), but in general it is not good way.